# spaCy needs a file that is not there: strings.json

Tags: python, spacy, pytextrank

I am running pytextrank were in its second stage, I get this error from spaCy:

```
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 371, in wrapped return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\spacy\\data\\en\\vocab\\strings.json'
```

I looked for strings.json but there is no such thing.

The interesting thing is that similar error with pathlib.py existed when I installed spaCy with the following error code:

```
OSError: Symbolic link privilege not held
```

Do you guys have any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: spacy is broken?

Comment: I have no idea, apparently, the 'spacy/vocab.pyx' calls for 'strings,json'

Comment: FWIW, we're adding support in `pytextrank` for installing directly through Anaconda -- currently it has PyPi support.

Answer (score 9):

Finallly, I can answer question in stackoverflow. I occurred same problem but solved it eventually. Here is my suggestion:

### 1. Download spaCy model from python -m spacy or github

both way are very convenient.

1). from python spacy:

```
python3 -m spacy download en
```

assume you are using python3+, the can be done automatically and generate new packages of model, which you can import via import en or using `spacy.load('en')`

2). from github

[transfer link](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases), selet the newest version and download it.

### 2. (if you not using python -m way then you want manually link the model) Link your downloaded model

this is the most important part, you must unzip your downloaded tar or gzip file, and get a folder, however this is still **not** the link path you want.

```
.
├── en_core_web_md-1.2.1
│   ├── deps
│   │   ├── config.json
│   │   └── model
│   ├── meta.json
│   ├── ner
│   │   ├── config.json
│   │   └── model
│   ├── pos
│   │   ├── config.json
│   │   └── model
│   └── vocab
│       ├── gazetteer.json
│       ├── lexemes.bin
│       ├── oov_prob
│       ├── serializer.json
│       ├── strings.json
│       └── vec.bin
```

you must link the folder with the structure. which spacy will link the folder via your link-shortcut name.

here is the link script you need:

```
base_path=`pwd`
sudo python3 -m spacy link ${base_path}/en_core_web_md-1.2.1 en_core_web --force
```

you can create a .sh file just alongside that folder and run it.

**that's it!**

Answer (score 1):

The `Symbolic link privilege not held` error usually occurs when you've installed spaCy and the models into a system directory, but your user does not have the required permissions to create symbolic links. To solve this, either run `download` or `link` again as administrator or, if that's not possible, use a `virtualenv` to install everything into a user directory instead (for more info on this, see the [troubleshooting docs](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/troubleshooting#symlink-privilege)).

As of v1.7.0, spaCy creates symlinks aka. [shortcut links](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/models#usage) in the `spacy/data` directory. This makes it easier to store your models wherever you want, install them as Python packages and load them using custom names, e.g. `spacy.load('my_model')`.

What likely happened in your case is that spaCy failed to set up this link because of the permissions error, and now can't find and load the model – including `vocab/strings.json`. (The way spaCy failed here is unideal, though – this has since been fixed in v1.7.3.)

Since the model is already installed, all you'd have to do is create a new symlink for it (either as admin, or in a `virtualenv`):

```
python -m spacy link en_core_web_sm en
```

(If you've downloaded a [different model](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/models#available), simply replace `en_core_web_sm` with the name of that model. `en` is the shortcut to use and can be any name you want.)

Edit: In case you only want to use the tokenizer and don't care about the models, or want to use one of the [supported languages](https://spacy.io/docs/api/language-models) that don't yet come with a statistical model, you can also just import the `Language` class in v1.7.3:

```
from spacy.fr import French
nlp = French()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your description was really helpful.